# one to Many mapping is not updating foreign key value

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many, spring-restcontroller, hibernate-onetomany

i create Employee Form where employee can select multiple skills from dropdown  and when submit button clicke form will get saved and i have foreignkeys table formskills where formid and skillid willbe mapped according to the selection , but i am unable to acxchive this mapping , i have tried many solution from online nothing helped me

Skills Dropdown
[FE- Skills dropdown image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PYn3.png)

FE Payload
[Form-payload image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ee9H.png)

DB Tables :
FormTable
[FormTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hPQ6.png)
SkillTable:
[Skillstable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hsWr.png)
FormSkills Table:
[Foreignkeys table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4LnB.png)

---

## BE Entites Code

FormModel:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="forms")
@SequenceGenerator(name="seq", initialValue=25, allocationSize=100)
public class FormModel implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE,generator = "seq")
    private Long formid;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String Email;
    private long mobileNumber;
    private int overalExperience;
    private int relaventExperience;
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    private String adarNumber;
    @Column(name="name_of_college")
    private String nameOfCollege;
    
    private String certificates;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="formmodel",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)
    private List<SkillsModel> skills;
```

**SkillsModel:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="skills")
public class SkillsModel implements Serializable{

    @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name="skill_id")
    private Integer skillid;
    
    @Column(name="skill_name")
    private String skillname;
    
    public SkillsModel() {}
    public SkillsModel(Integer skillid, String skillname) {
        super();
        this.skillid = skillid;
        this.skillname = skillname;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="formskills",joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="skillid")},inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="formid")})
    private FormModel formmodel;
    
    
    public SkillsModel(Integer skillid, String skillname, FormModel formmodel) {
        super();
        this.skillid = skillid;
        this.skillname = skillname;
        this.formmodel = formmodel;
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
public class FormController {
    
    @Autowired
    private FormService service;
    
    
    @GetMapping("/getskills")
    public List<SkillsModel> getskills() {
        return service.getskills();
    }
    
    @PostMapping(value="/saveuser")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> createUser(@RequestBody FormModel model) {    
              System.out.println(model.getSkills().get(0));
             FormModel modelform=service.createuserform(model);
           
        URI location=ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}")
                .buildAndExpand(modelform.getFormid()).toUri();
        return ResponseEntity.created(location).build() ;
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/getforms")
    public List<FormModel> getformdata() {
         return service.getformdata();
    }
```

**Service:**

```
@Service
public class FormService {
    
    @Autowired
    private FormRepository formrepo;
    @Autowired
    private Skillsrepository skillsrepo;
    
    public FormModel createuserform(FormModel userform) {
           FormModel modelform=formrepo.save(userform);
        return  modelform;
    }
    
    public List<SkillsModel> getskills() {
        List<SkillsModel> getskills=new ArrayList<>();
        
        getskills=skillsrepo.findAll();
        for(SkillsModel model :getskills) {
            System.out.println(model.getSkillid() + model.getSkillname());
        }
        return getskills;
    }

    public List<FormModel> getformdata() {
         List<FormModel> formlist= formrepo.findAll();
         System.out.println(formlist);
        return formlist;
    }
```

Comment: Employee Form where employee select multiple skills from dropdown and when submit button clicke form will get saved

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is, when inserting a `FormModel` entity, the system should also insert all of the associated `SkillsModel` entities automatically, without iterating over the List and inserting each Skill one by one, is that correct?

If that's the case, make the following changes:

**SkillsModel:**

```
public class SkillsModel implements Serializable {

...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "formid")
    private FormModel formmodel;

...

}
```

**FormService:**

```
@Service
public class FormService {

...

    public FormModel createuserform(FormModel userform) {
    
        for (SkillsModel skill: userform.getSkills()) {
            skill.setFormmodel(userform);
        }
    
        FormModel modelform = formrepo.save(userform);
        return  modelform;
    }

...

}
```

Comment: i am trying to map formid to each selected skill in  skillstable in db , it has to happen with hibernate one to many mapping , but its not working for me , i tried your solution but `(skill.setformodel)` is not adding any values to formid in skilltable in db .